# Replacing bulb in heater unit on Peugeot 207

Tags: peugeot, bulbs, heater-control, center-console

I have a Peugeot 207 with a manual heater unit with a failed bulb, and need details on how to replace it.

I have search online for an answer but have come up with not very much.

I found out I need to remove the two silver strips on the center console, unscrew the heater panel, then push it in and down to release it - this is as far as I've got. Once I've pushed it in, there seems to be no way of removing the unit from the console, as the console itself is now in the way and there are a bunch of cables and wire connected to the unit. It seems nearly impossible to replace the bulb.

If anyone has successfully done this, please, how did you manage it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in addition to the two strips there is a smaller strip just below the heater panel with a locking button on it.  You can loosen that and lift it down to release the heater panel.

This [link](http://www.peugeotforums.com/forums/207-36/207-changing-bulbs-behind-fan-temperature-controls-18959/) appears to have more detail on the procedure.

Good luck.